# Socket.emit (client) not emitting unless I run in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am trying to emit an event when the client socket connects. Here is my code.

```
socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('connect');
    socket.emit('status.update', { 
        conversationId: conversationId, 
        userId: userId, 
        online: true 
    });
});
```

This code is also nested in the `$(document).ready(function(){})`

This is the listener on the server:

```
   socket.on('status.update', function(data){
       io.to(data.userId).emit('update.status', { conversationId: data.conversationId, online: data.online });
   });
```

This is what is supposed to happen:

**Client (user 1):** when socket connects, emit event. In this case, it is 'status.update', passing some data.

**Server:** On status.update emit 'update.status' to the user extracted from data

**Client (user 2 or recipient):** on 'update.status' the online status for user 1 is updated in their chatbox.

What is currently happening:

I am testing this with 2 separate browsers open. user 1 in Chrome and user 2 (recipient) in firefox. I have the console open in firefox the entire time I am testing with a breakpoint on the `socket.on('update.status')` listener .

When user 1 connects and the console is closed, the console still logs the 'connect' message, but does not emit the event. I know this because the breakpoint is not triggered on the recipient side.

When user 1 connects and the console is open, the 'connect' message is still logged in the console and the event is fired on emit and now the breakpoint is triggered on the recipient side.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an event listener setup on your server for handling the `status.update` event?

Comment: Yes.  The listener is set up for 'status.update' which emits a 'update.status' event to the recipient. The problem is the 'status.update' event is only triggered on the user 1 side when the console is open.

Comment: I'm positive that's not true. Are you logging anything on the server side to show you that it's successfully capturing the `status.update` event from the first user?

Comment: Also can in the Developer Tools (in Chrome at least) in Network Tab you can view opened websocket connections to view each message that has reached the client or has been sent to the server. Can you see your messages there?

Comment: i edited the post to show the listener on the server